# left tab completion in bash or zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, tab-completion

When I use standard tab completion in bash or zsh, I type the first part of a filename or path, then hit  to complete the word. This works well unless I'm in a directory full of files where all of the variation in filenames is at the end of the word, e.g. A directory full of time-stamped files which all start with the same prefix:

```
foo-20120701124501.log
foo-20120701124531.log
foo-20120701124601.log
foo-20120701124631.log
foo-20120701124701.log
foo-20120701124731.log
```

In this case, if I type `foo<tab>` I'll get `foo-20120701124` -- I can tab again, and see all of the files... I would have to type in the next 3 characters to get to a unique file name.

I'm wondering if there is a way to type for instance `4731.log` and then complete beginning of the word. I'm guessing that this would be difficult in bash, because bash completion uses  `$COMP_CWORD` and `$COMP_KEY` for its programmable completion, and from the way that I'm reading it, I don't think that those would allow for leftward word completion. I don't know enough about completion inside zsh to know where to start looking in the man pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only work if there is a leading command before hitting tab.  Likely is not what you are looking for but the only was I could get the desired results.  The below example should work in your case.  You just need to be at the end of the *4731.log and hit tab 1 time.  If it is unique it will autocomplete.

```
ls *4731.log
```

Comment: Yep, worked like a charm. I generated a series of files using `for i in {1..10}; do touch $(date -d "$i days $RANDOM seconds ago" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S); done`... this created a series of files which looked like `20120915165427 20120916121328 20120917180952` etc. If I use `ls *09<tab>`, it doesn't expand, but `*09*<tab>` does.